# report builder - queries returning incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have set a reporting project where I would like to get stats for my tables and later integrate this into a webservice. For the following queries though, I am getting incorrect results and I will note where below:

1 - Get the number of new entries for a given day

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordsCount,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadded AS float)) 
 AS datetime)as collectionDate 
 FROM TFeed GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadded AS float))
 AS datetime) order by collectionDate
```

works fine and I am able to put this in a bar graph successfully.

2 - Get the top 10 searchterms with the highest records per searchterm requested by a given client in the last 10 days

```
SELECT TOP 10 searchterm, clientId, COUNT(*) AS TermResults FROM TFeed 
where dateadded > getdate() - 10 GROUP BY 
searchterm,clientId order by TermResults desc
```

does not work
If I do a query in the Database for one of those terms that returns 98 in the report, the result is 984 in the database.

3 - I need to get the number of new records per client for a given day as well.

Also I was wondering if it is possible to put these queries into one report and not individual reports for each query which is not a big deal but having to cut and paste into one doc afterwards is tedious.

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #2,

```
WITH tmp as
(
 SELECT clientId, searchTerm, COUNT(1) as TermResults,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (partition by clientId
    ORDER BY clientId, COUNT(1) DESC) as rnk
 FROM TFeed
 WHERE dateadded > GETDATE() - 10 
 GROUP BY clientId, searchterm 
)
SELECT *
FROM   tmp
WHERE rnk < 11
```

USE RANK() if you want to skip a rank if there are two matches (if lets say term1 and term2 have the same number of count, they are both rank 1 and the following term will be ranked 3rd instead of 2nd

For #3, 
you can define multiple datasets within one report. Then you would just create three charts / table and associate those with their respective datasets

Comment: very helpful, works great in sql server but in report builder the '<' generates an error, illegal syntax, expecting valid start name;; will try to find a way around that.

Comment: you could just create a stored procedure in sql server and call that stored procedure from your SSRS report